# Using AngularJs to update values in barchart and piechart using data from grid

Tags: json, angularjs, bar-chart, pie-chart, ng-grid

Actually I am new to AngularJs , and i wanted to create a bar and pie chart depending on the data from json .
Everything is working fine , except for one weird bug . 
The values in the charts are updated only when an event like re sizing window is performed . I do not want this to happen .
I tried using $scope.$apply but somehow it didn't work

M putting the link of plunker - http://embed.plnkr.co/Yd2BZYSsDEBOAhVIz64B/preview

the main files are index.html and main.js .

few code snippets -
in index.html

```
<nvd3-pie-chart 
         id="pieChart"
         data="aggStatus"
         noData="Data not present"
         x="xFunction()"
         y="yFunction()" 
         width="400"
         height="300"
         showLabels="true"
         tooltips="true"
        noData="no data"
         donut="true"
         donutRatio="0.2"
         color="colorFunction()"
         labelType="percent">
         <svg></svg>
     </nvd3-pie-chart>
```

**in main.js**

```
$scope.aggStatus = [
                        { "key": "Completed", "y":'' },
                        { "key": "Failed", "y":'' },


                  ];
```

Here the y values are decided from the data in grid

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.myData.length;i++){

        if($scope.myData[i].Status==="Completed")
            $scope.aggStatus[0].y++;
        else
            $scope.aggStatus[1].y++;}
```

Comment: You should put your code, or at least the most important parts of it, in the question to increase your chances for a reply.

Comment: @marko- in Index.html - i have created a nvd3 pie chart .                                Now in main.js - $scope.aggStatus = [
                           { "key": "Completed", "y":'' },
                            { "key": "Failed", "y":'' },                         
                      ];                                                                                                   y value is calculated using grid data . For eg - if there are two rows with status as Complete then its y value would be 2 .                                              This is achieved using a for loop

Comment: Could have something to do with the http request and the watchers perhaps, and on resize it updates the data?

Comment: @jedanput Yes it updates the data in pie chart as well as bar chart on resize . Just visit the plunkr link . Resize the window , and then you can see that pie chart is visible with updated data . Plus , if you will choose any option from the select panel , you will notice that the rows in grid gets updated but the chart would get updated only on resizing the window or by performing any window event like right click and select an option

Comment: @jedanput Though the values that will appear on chart gets updated ( i checked that by displaying the values using ng-bind on th frontend ) but still the chart display is updated only after resize or any window event